# Count rows where value is between two numbers and group by a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I am super annoyed with this - apologize in advance if it shows. 
*All of my work is on a different (work) computer - yeah, imagine living this way.

Two columns: `accountid`, `amount`

```
accountid    amount
1            500
2            440
1            420
2            300
```

result should be:

```
accountid    count_amount_400_500
1            2
2            1
```

I'm trying to count the number of times an accountid has amounts between 400 and 500 and put that in separate column.

I thought something like this, and 100 other similar iterations, would work:
`df.loc[df['amount'].between(400,500).groupby('accountid').nunique()`
but they don't.

Someone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `groupby`+`agg`

```
df.groupby('accountid').amount.agg(lambda s: s.between(400, 500).sum())
```

```
accountid       amount      
1               2
2               1
```

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend use `pd.cut`

```
df.groupby([df.accountid,pd.cut(df.amount,[0,400,500,600])]).size()
Out[109]: 
accountid  amount    
1          (400, 500]    2
2          (0, 400]      1
           (400, 500]    1
dtype: int64
```

Or change to another layout with `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.accountid,pd.cut(df.amount,[0,400,500,600]))
Out[114]: 
amount     (0, 400]  (400, 500]
accountid                      
1                 0           2
2                 1           1
```